3 NVME Acer 2TB drives have the same Hardware UUID?
The Question: Is it normal for three drives made by the same manufacturer (all having the same capacity 2TB in this case) to have the same Hardware UUID in Linux?
Not the Partitions, the hardware.
The Details: Over the course of a year, I purchased three Acer 2TB NVME Drives from Newegg. I had installed two of them in the same Notebook (Acer Nitro 2022), and while using Windows they worked without error.
I recently installed Fedora 41 on the Acer Nitro 2022, and while in the Anaconda installer, Anaconda thru an error/warning that there were two devices with the same Hardware UUID. I ended up having to remove one to finish the installation.
I was curious since I have another Notebook with one of these Acer 2TB NVME drives, so I ran the following command on both Notebooks to see if the Nitro error was a fluke:
"ls -la /dev/disk/by-id"
For both Notebooks, the same Hardware UUID is reported under the device "nvme0n1":
"nvme-uuid.df8e86d6-8a47-9916-2e43-8e8b6efdb7cd"

For context, none of the three drives have ever been cloned by me. If they were cloned, then it was by the manufacturer.  When searching for a solution all I found were instructions to change the UUID on the partitions. If I am mistaken then please let me know that there is a safe way to change the Hardware UUID.
